# Unable to delete git remote branch with a special character

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-branch

Please, before mark this question as duplicated, read carefully.

If you list branches, it appears like this:

```
$git branch -a
  remotes/origin/feat/verify-<C3>email
```

The branch name is:

```
origin/feat/verify-√email
```

If you try to access the branch url from Github Dashboard:

```
The github page broke into a HTTP error 400
```

If you try to delete the branch:

```
$ git push origin --delete feat/verify-√email
error: unable to delete 'feat/verify-√email': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://mataide@github.com/mataide/proak-website.git'
```

Delete by pattern:

```
git branch -d -r $(git branch --list origin/feat/ve* -r)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feat/verify-?email': Unable to create '/Users/marcus/Documents/Workspace/proak-website/.git/refs/remotes/origin/feat/verify-?email.lock': Illegal byte sequence
error: Error deleting remote-tracking branch 'origin/feat/verify-?email'
```

Same error if you try by the name: feat/verify-email.
Also doent work if you try to delete by tools like Sourcetree.

I just want to delete the branch, any help?

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365592/delete-git-branch-by-anything-not-name

Comment: @Renat, tried the solution, but also gives an error. I will update the question.

Comment: Any chance you can do it via a UI _on the remote_  like github, gitlab, etc?

Comment: @JakeParis, I tried using Sourcetree. It also gives the error as not found.

Comment: Yes, but isn't SourceTree a local Application? I was thinking that perhaps the remote UI would have better handling of special characters in the branch name.

Comment: Can you change the branch name locally?

Answer (score 0):

The `√` character that I cut and pasted from your posting is a Unicode character for square root: U+221A—see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_symbol.  The one actually in the other Git appears to be a code-byte-C3 in some non-Unicode character set.  You'll need to get the other Git to remove that somehow.

The `git push --delete` is a good idea, but you have to send the exact byte sequence to that other Git.  It's not clear to me how to do that from whatever terminal session you're using.  If you're on MacOS, you could edit up a shell script file that has the right byte sequence: just run `git branch -r > /tmp/script`, open the file in a suitable editor (e.g., `vim`), delete all the irrelevant lines, and insert `git push origin --delete` in front of the remaining one with the bad name.  Then run the resulting script, e.g., `sh /tmp/script`.  With no human hands (or editor) touching the bytes on the line, the original byte code sequence should remain in place.

Using `git branch -d -r` will, even if it works, not really help, as the name will keep coming back as long as it exists in the *other* Git.  However, once you've gotten rid of the bad name on the other Git—which might require outside help, e.g., from the GitHub folks—a `git fetch --prune` may not be able to discard the remote-tracking name in your own repository either.  (Try it first though.)

Given that your OS won't let you create the lock file for that name, you'll need to manually remove the right entry, which will be a line in your `.git/packed-refs` file.  Use a text-file-only editor (not a rich-text editor) that can handle newline-terminated lines (not CRLF) and delete the line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using Mac OS. The terminal has support for Unicode. So for me, type the cli or run through sh script, the result should be the same. I tried the script created by vim. The error is the same. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In that case, maybe the upstream branch is already deleted, and you just need to run `git fetch -p` (and if that fails, run `vim .git/packed-refs` and delete the bad line).

Comment: Its not deleted because I can still access it inside github dashboard. You can create a new branch with this unicode, it will failure in the same way.

Comment: Interesting. You might have to get GitHub support to delete it, then.